# Looking for topographic map of Bogota, Colombia, with elevation contour lines

Tags: data, elevation, contour, topography, south-america

I'm looking for a topographic map of Bogota, Colombia; specifically, we want to get the elevation contour lines, and export that layer to CAD.

If anyone knows of any free places to find this data, we would love to hear it! I've been looking through some of the sources here http://freegisdata.rtwilson.com/ - but I'm not very familiar with that huge list.

Does anyone know of a specific link in there that would be best to investigate?

Comment: You should ask in [OpenData SE site](https://opendata.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1):

I usually use The NASA Shuttle Radar Topographic Mission (SRTM).

"The SRTM digital elevation data, produced by NASA originally, is a major breakthrough in digital mapping of the world, and provides a major advance in the accessibility of high quality elevation data for large portions of the tropics and other areas of the developing world."

The link of the main page is the following: 
http://www.cgiar-csi.org/data/srtm-90m-digital-elevation-database-v4-1

And the link of the Download Data Interface is the following:
Here, you just have to select the grid that you want to download

http://srtm.csi.cgiar.org/SELECTION/inputCoord.asp

I am not sure if it is exactly what you are looking for ...